# Scalable webhosting solution

Tags: cloud, storage, web-hosting, data-storage

I currently operate a website that allows users to save their creation to a database and share it with others. Very much like twitter or an image hosting platform. I am currently looking for a scale-able hosting solution that can host a potentially large amount of data.

I was thinking AWS might be a solution, but I'm a little bit confused by their offers. I cant pay upfront for a huge amount of storage. So I was thinking of looking for a solution that adds more space as needed.

If anyone could point me towards some different options I have that would be great :D

I currently pay for a static 80GB web VPS. As users create more content, old content will get overwritten after a certain amount of the storage is filled up. This is good enough for my current needs, but I'm looking to future proof my storage, and not erase user data.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to make your site elastically scalable as the workload increases, there is a very simple solution for that with AWS, it's called "Serverless"

Check it out on their site, hopefully, it's useful. You might need to learn a few things before it's useful to your use case but it's quite easy to understand.

There is also "Kubernetes" from GCP, check that out as well, it's a bit more complicated than serverless but a very brilliant solution for high growth applications.